# JSF - setPropertyActionListener sets value but getValue return null

Tags: jsf, actionlistener

I have a xhtml page like :

```
<h:form id="forma">
        <h:dataTable value="#{smestaj.savSmestaj}" var="s">
        <h:column>

            <c:facet name="header">Action</c:facet>

            <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{s.edituj}" 
                                       rendered="#{not s.prom}" >

            <c:setPropertyActionListener target="#{smestaj.izabraniS}" value="#{s}"/>
            </h:commandButton>

             </h:column>

          </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And in bean Smestaj :

```
public class Smestaj {    
Smestaj izabraniS;
        /** other properties and methods **/
        public Smestaj getIzabraniS() {
            return izabraniS;
        }
        public void setIzabraniS(Smestaj izabraniS) {
            this.izabraniS = izabraniS;
            System.out.println("Setting on... "+this.izabraniS.id);
        }
    public String edituj()
        {
            nekiEditovan=1;
            System.out.println("I take ..."+izabraniS);

            return null;
        }
}
```

First, setIzabraniS method print "Setting on.... 1" (or other number) and then method edituj prints "I take null". Does anyone knows what is problem? My bean is in session scope.

If I try to send integer to bean everything working fine. 
Thanks :)

Comment: What is the scope of your ManagedBean?

Comment: Do you have an `f:event type="preRenderView"` on your page? And, don't you have a `@ManagedBean` WITH a `Smestaj` attribute?

Comment: I don't have f:event type="preRenderedView" and also don't have @ManagedBean with Smestaj attribute....  Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint in your constructor to see if it gets called AFTER the setter? Because of your design, I think your constructor is getting called AFTER the setter...